# Change Chrome's JS default behaviour

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is it possible to edit the default way JS works in the Google Chrome browser?

For example: 
    I can make a webpage to don't display the context menu when the left mouse is clicked. Can I set this behaviour to all the pages I visit within the browser? Or this would be a open door to crash pages?

Comment: yes, either make your own extension or just use greasemonkey/tampermonkey and do your own script

Comment: javascript works how it works and you cannot change that. You can override default methods per-page or browser wide with a TamperMonkey script or a browser extension. Per your example... Javascript has the ability to control the context menu so you could make your browser not show context menus by using javascript in a user script or extention but it would only affect you and a page could override your override. Why would you want to disable right click browser wide?

Comment: Are you looking something like this? http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/dhtml/article.php/3470591

Comment: Just an example haha. I thought you will answer me to override object prototypes. Even tho, I would like to know if is possible to access all the default Chrome's JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this tool to inject custom javascript in any website.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en